# Identify Bimodal Distributions in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have data on products, some of which show bimodal distributions (see image for example).

I want to find products for which there are two peaks programmatically. The following attempts to do that by determining whether the previous and next count are less than the current count when sorting by product, price. Does that actually work? Is there a better way?

```
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
("prod_name",135.63,1.0),
("prod_name",159.04,4.0),
("prod_name",182.29,16.0),
("prod_name",216.55,18.0),
("prod_name",231.18,1.0),
("prod_name",289.0 ,2.0),
("prod_name",303.31,8.0),
("prod_name",320.88,14.0),
("prod_name",345.06,4.0),
("prod_name",360.85,4.0)
).toDF("product", "price", "count")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("bimodal")


spark.sql("""
with peaks as (
select *, lag(count) over (order by product, price) previous, lag(count, -1) over (order by product, price) next
from bimodal)
select product, price, case when count > previous and count > next then 'peak' else 'not_a_peak' end peak
from peaks
order by product, price
""").show
```

It works for my example as it returns:

```
+---------+------+----------+
|  product| price|      peak|
+---------+------+----------+
|prod_name|135.63|not_a_peak|
|prod_name|159.04|not_a_peak|
|prod_name|182.29|not_a_peak|
|prod_name|216.55|      peak|
|prod_name|231.18|not_a_peak|
|prod_name| 289.0|not_a_peak|
|prod_name|303.31|not_a_peak|
|prod_name|320.88|      peak|
|prod_name|345.06|not_a_peak|
|prod_name|360.85|not_a_peak|
+---------+------+----------+
```

[image: Bimodal Distribution]